# From iphone app to face.com api: upload raw image

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I just test the face.com face recognition api and I have success with json requests:

```
NSString *url = @"http://api.face.com/faces/detect.json?api_key=myapi&api_secret=mysecret&urls=http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/_/47363849/Christina+Aguilera+HQ+PNG.png";

// Create new SBJSON parser object
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

// Perform request and get JSON back as a NSData object
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

// Get JSON as a NSString from NSData response
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// parse the JSON response into an object
// Here we're using NSArray since we're parsing an array of JSON status objects
NSDictionary *obj = [parser objectWithString:json_string];

//
NSString *status = [obj objectForKey:@"status"];

//
NSLog(@"status: %@", status);
```

This works when I pass the api key, secret and the IMAGE ON THE WEB as GET params, like:

```
http://api.face.com/faces/detect.json?api_key=4b4b4c6d54c37&api_secret= &urls= http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2566/3896283279_0209be7a67.jpg
```

Now, I want to upload a raw image data from my app...but this is not so well documented on the site:

http://developers.face.com/docs/api/faces-detect/

There it says:

Code:
Optional    [no name]   The raw image data for the photo (when instead of url, an image is uploaded)

This is the problem:

How do I pass the raw data as POST along with the apikey and secret? 
I know it must be as POST, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raw data = NSData, so all you need to do is append the imageData to the URL, as done below.

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.face.com/faces/detect.json?api_key=myapi&api_secret=mysecret&code=%@", imageData];
```